# Number of options of an option field - Select

Tags: angular, html-select

I am working with Angular 2 and I am having problems to get the number of options of a select.

I am able to get the total number of options that have a select:

```
<select class="form-control"(change)="carSelected(index = $event.target.selectedIndex);"
    required>
    <option></option>
    <option *ngFor="let oneCar of car.fourDoors">{{oneCar.name}}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let oneCar of car.twoDoors">{{oneCar.name}}</option>
</select>
```

using `index = $event.target.selectedIndex` and it perfectly works.

**What i need**
but what i need is to check how many options of `car.fourDoors` are. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the length of any array call its member length

```
car.fourDoors.length
```

Comment: Sometimes I should think about my questions :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`Object.keys(car.fourDoors).length`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
*ngFor="let oneCar of car.fourDoors; let i = index;"
```

and then the {{ i }} variable will tell you how many there are. Likewise, you could just get car.fourDoors.length as well.